# Passing member function with all arguments to std::function

Tags: c++, c++11

How can I create a std::function from member function without need for typing std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, etc - I would like to "placehold" all arguments, saving only the object itself.

```
struct Foo{
  int bar(int,float,bool) {return 0;}
};
int baz(int,float,bool) {return 0;}
int main() {
  Foo object;
  std::function<int(int,float,bool)> fun1 = baz; // OK
  std::function<int(int,float,bool)> fun2 = std::bind(&Foo::bar, object); // WRONG, needs placeholders
}
```

I don't want to provide arguments at this stage, I just want to store function + object somewhere. For example I would like to have std::vector with both global functions and member functions. It was easy to do with FastDelegate (`fastdelegate::MakeDelegate(object, &Class::function)`).

I don't want to use lambda as it would require me to retype arguments as well. I just want old FastDelegate behaviour.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use function template which will deduce all member function parameter types, like this:

```
template<typename Obj, typename Result, typename ...Args>
auto make_delegate(const Obj &x, Result (Obj::*fun)(Args...)) -> // ...
```

And will return special delegate object, which will contain your object (or pointer to it) and just forward all passed arguments to member function of underlying object:

```
template<typename Obj, typename Result, typename ...Args>
struct Delegate
{
    Obj x;
    Result (Obj::*f)(Args...);

    template<typename ...Ts>
    Result operator()(Ts&&... args)
    {
        return (x.*f)(forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }
};
```

You will get following usage syntax:

```
function<int(int,float,bool)> fun = make_delegate(object, &Foo::bar);
```

Here is full example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
    int bar(int x, float y, bool z)
    {
        cout << "bar: " << x << " " << y << " " << z << endl;
        return 0;
    }
};

int baz(int x, float y, bool z)
{
    cout << "baz: " << x << " " << y << " " << z << endl;
    return 0;
}

template<typename Obj, typename Result, typename ...Args>
struct Delegate
{
    Obj x;
    Result (Obj::*f)(Args...);

    template<typename ...Ts>
    Result operator()(Ts&&... args)
    {
        return (x.*f)(forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }
};

template<typename Obj, typename Result, typename ...Args>
auto make_delegate(const Obj &x, Result (Obj::*fun)(Args...))
    -> Delegate<Obj, Result, Args...>
{
    Delegate<Obj, Result, Args...> result{x, fun};
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    Foo object;
    function<int(int,float,bool)> fun[] =
    {
        baz,
        make_delegate(object, &Foo::bar) // <---- usage
    };
    for(auto &x : fun)
        x(1, 1.0, 1);
}
```

Output is:

```
baz: 1 1 1
bar: 1 1 1
```

[**Live Demo on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3c73599b2ffdf25)

Comment: +1. I wrote almost same code : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18b39266e9e9f986

Comment: @Nawaz It is almost same indeed. Only significant difference I spot is how object stored. I thought to use pointer originally, but he used `std::bind(&Foo::bar, object)` - so I thought that he want to store copy.

Comment: The solution in the answer seems to be a bit less robust for me, as for my templated class compilation-attempts yield `[...] is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed: struct Delegate`, whereas `smart_bind` by @Nawaz works. However, for Nawaz' code I also get an error when I try to **bind const methods**. I have tried to modify the solution but wasn't able to fix the problem. Any hints or is this a new question rather ?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use placeholders, then `std::bind` is not for you:

Use lambda:

```
Foo object;

std::function<int(int,float,bool)> fun = [&object](int a, float b, bool c) {
        return object.bar(a,b,c);
};
```

You can capture `object` by value if you wish. Perhaps you realize this is no better than using placeholders, as you're typing parameters anyway — in fact you type *more* in this case!

Comment: This is not what I want. Object is not stored with the function.

Comment: Wojtek wants to assign an `int Foo::bar(int, float, bool)` to a `std::function<int, float, bool>`

Comment: @Wojtek If you want copy of the object to be stored (like the answer you accepted), just change the capture mode of lambda `[object]` or `[=object]`. It should have the same effect as `Delegate` structure.

Comment: @zahir this answer has been completely changed after my comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with variadic generic lambdas in C++14:

```
template<typename F, typename C>
auto smart_bind(F f, C* c)
{
  return [c, f](auto&&... args) { return (c->*f)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); };
}

// In your code:
std::function<int(int,float,bool)> fun2 = smart_bind(&Foo::bar, &object);
```

Live demo: https://ideone.com/deR4fy