# Passing function as an argument to different function in different file

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

So, I want to pass function, that is in engine.cpp file, as an argument, and that's what I did:

```
typedef RFun(*wsk)(double, int);

RFun Engine::f_line(double *&values, int howmany)
{
    RFun line;

    for(int i = 0; i < howmany; i++)
    {
        line.result_values[i] = (2 * values[i]) + 6;
    }

    return line;
}

RFun counter(double *&values, int howmany, wsk function)
{
    return function(*values, howmany);
}
```

and now I want to call the counter function in other .cpp file and pass f_line function inside as parameter. How can I achieve that?

Comment: [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) comes to mind...

Comment: It looks to me like you intend to pass `Engine::f_iline` with a`wsk` function pointer. If that's the case you will encounter difficulties becase the argument types don't match (`double` and `double *&` are not the same) and `Engine::f_file` is a member function which is not compatible with pointers to functions. You would need a pointer to member function.

Comment: To clarify what @FrançoisAndrieux said: `&f_line` is type `RFun (Engine::*)(double*&, int)`, not `RFun (*)(double, int)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple [example](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/73423/) how to use std::function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

void func1()
{
  // a function that takes no parameters and does nothing
  cout << "in global func1" << endl;
}

class Example
{
public:
  int value;

  void memberfunc()
  {
    cout << "in memberfunc.  value=" << value << endl;
  }
};

void CallAFunction( std::function< void() > functocall )
{
  functocall();  // call it normally
}

int main()
{
  // call a global function
  CallAFunction( func1 );  // prints "in global func1"

  // call a member function (a little more complicated):
  Example e;
  e.value = 10;
  CallAFunction( std::bind( &Example::memberfunc, std::ref(e) ) );
    // prints "in memberfunc.  value=10"
}
```

Try it out [here](http://ideone.com/ZRYB0e)

> Success time: 0 memory: 15240 signal:0
>
> in global func1 
>   in memberfunc. value=10

Comment: Okay, but I have to pass some parameters to my function.

Comment: @MikołajPopieluch see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691934/passing-member-function-with-all-arguments-to-stdfunction